# I can't make freestyle to work in blender 2.8 (file provided)

Tags: freestyle

I can make freestyle to work when I start a new project. But I can't make it work when I'm working in my scene. I tried reading lots of post everywhere but I can't solve this problem. Please help me.

Here is the file in case someone is willing to help.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/fcf321ap1lntuk8/Test_Anime.blend/file

Comment: Hi, welcome! If possible please add some detail about how you have setup the freestyle for your use case, maybe add a relevant screenshot with the question image tool, it will help others to understand what you did, and help you or learn from your example, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You overfiltered the line selection.
Here is a working setting:

[image: Settings]
[image: Result render]

And [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqqqd8nrlnmoros/Test%20Anime.zip?dl=0/) is the blender file.